# Getting Mailbox Aliases for Personal Accounts in Microsoft Graph API not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to get email aliases through Microsoft Graph:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=proxyAddresses
```

This worked for an Office 365 account of mine(business account) but I'm not able to get the aliases for a personal account (outlook.com,hotmail.com). I'm not able to find any comprehensive documentation on this either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `proxyAddress` property is only returned for Azure Active Directory objects. The only properties returned for a personal Microsoft Account (MSA) are:

```
{
    "displayName": "",
    "surname": "",
    "givenName": "",
    "id": "",
    "userPrincipalName": "",
    "businessPhones": [],
    "jobTitle": "",
    "mail": "",
    "mobilePhone": "",
    "officeLocation": "",
    "preferredLanguage": ""
}
```

Outlook.com/Hotmail has a different infrastructure/architecture than AAD/Exchange. While Graph can interact with MSA accounts, there are some inherent limitations due to these differences. There are similar differences between OneDrive for Business (i.e. SharePoint) and personal OneDrive as well.

Comment: Is there a way for getting the aliases for email address mailbox of the user?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no.